# C++ multiline string raw literal

Tags: c++

We can define a string with multiline like this:

```
const char* text1 = "part 1"
                    "part 2"
                    "part 3"
                    "part 4";

const char* text2 = "part 1\
                     part 2\
                     part 3\
                     part 4";
```

How about with raw literal, I tried all, no one works

```
std::string text1 = R"part 1"+
                    R"part 2"+ 
                    R"part 3"+
                    R"part 4";

std::string text2 = R"part 1"
                    R"part 2" 
                    R"part 3"
                    R"part 4";

std::string text3 = R"part 1\
                      part 2\ 
                      part 3\
                      part 4";

std::string text4 = R"part 1
                      part 2 
                      part 3
                      part 4";
```

Comment: What does "no one works" mean?  Do you get an error message?

Comment: Be aware that you are concatenating the strings without intervening newlines.

Comment: what are you trying to do? and you have syntax error for raw string. [see this](http://ideone.com/KuQi9o)

Comment: Those aren't multi-line strings - but strings written on multiple lines.

Comment: my string is too long, i want define them in multiple lines, it is easier for me to read in the code

Comment: What is `R`? Is that a macro?

Comment: you are right, just define it in multi-lines

Comment: Language Lawyers:  What's the difference between a *literal* and a *raw literal*.

Comment: http://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/10/16/cpp-11-raw-strings-literals-tutorial/

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey, It's like L for wide string literals, except for raw string literals.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews 2.14.5/1: "A string literal that has an `R` in the prefix is a _raw string literal_." (e.g. `R"**(\n)**"`)  13.5.8/4:" A _raw literal operator_ is a literal operator with a single parameter whose type is `const char*`.  (e.g. `MyClass operator "" _foo( const char* );`)  Those two phrases are the only technical definitions involving "raw" in the Standard.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Note that raw string literals are delimited by `R"(` and `)"` (or you can add to the delimiter by adding characters between the quote and the parens if you need additional 'uniqueness').

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

int main () 
{
    // raw-string literal example with the literal made up of separate, concatenated literals
    std::string s = R"(abc)" 
                    R"( followed by not a newline: \n)"
                    " which is then followed by a non-raw literal that's concatenated \n with"
                    " an embedded non-raw newline";

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is R"( supposed to be R(", I am not on computer, can't try.

Comment: @Giswin, No, the parentheses go inside the quotation marks. And perhaps something like ideone or Coliru would still work on your phone (or whatever you're on).

Comment: @Giswin: the code example is a small, complete program that was copy/pasted from a file that compiled and ran using VS 2013 and GCC 4.8.0. So there should hopefully be no typo's in there.

Answer (score 44):

Just write it as you want it:

```
std::string text = R"(part 1
part 2
part 3
part 4)";
```

The other thing you didn't put in was the required pair of parentheses around the entire string.

Also keep in mind any leading spaces on the part 2-4 lines that you might put in to keep the code formatted are included, as well as a leading newline to get part 1 with the others, so it does make it rather ugly to see in the code sometimes.

An option that might be plausible for keeping things tidy, but still using raw string literals is to concatenate newlines:

```
R"(part 1)" "\n" 
R"(part 2)" "\n" 
R"(part 3)" "\n" 
R"(part 4)"
```

Comment: I guess it would be useful to split a long string to separate lines of code without including "\n"s. This is the case with complicated regular expressions. But your answer introduces newlines to the string, which might be not the intended result.

Comment: @NikolaiK., Fair, it's been some years, but I probably expected that the embedded newlines were desired. The second part can be adapted pretty straightforwardly to remove newlines from the result.

Comment: Thanks. required alot of IQ to brute force that you could mix raw string with regular string.