# C++ multi line string not working as expected

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, windows-7

I'm trying to create a banner for an application on Windows.

```
// C Libraries:
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

// Namespaces:
using namespace std;

const char *BANNER[] = R"BANNER(
             .-') _                              .-')
           (  OO) )                            ( OO ).
 ,--. ,--.  /     '._ ,-.-')  ,--.      ,-.-') (_)---\_)
 |  | |  |  |'--...__)|  |OO) |  |.-')  |  |OO)/    _ |
 |  | | .-')'--.  .--'|  |  \ |  | OO ) |  |  \\  :` `.
 |  |_|( OO )  |  |   |  |(_/ |  |`-' | |  |(_/ '..`''.)
 |  | | `-' /  |  |  ,|  |_.'(|  '---.',|  |_.'.-._)   \
('  '-'(_.-'   |  | (_|  |    |      |(_|  |   \       /
 `-----'      `--'    `--'    `------'  `--'    `-----')BANNER";

char* getCmdOption(char ** begin, char ** end, const std::string & option)
{
    char ** itr = find(begin, end, option);
    if (itr != end && ++itr != end)
    {
        return *itr;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool cmdOptionExists(char** begin, char** end, const std::string& option)
{
    return find(begin, end, option) != end;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    printf("%s\n", BANNER);

    if(cmdOptionExists(argv, argv+argc, "-h"))
    {
        cout << "Help Menu";
    }


    if (cmdOptionExists(argv, argv + argc, "-a"))
    {
        cout << "Adobe";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've read on multiple threads and multiple websites that you can use the syntax `R"(<string here>)";` or `R"BANNER(<string here>)BANNER";` to create a multiple line string. However when I got to compile this code I get the following errors:

```
utilis.cpp(9) : error C2001: newline in constant
utilis.cpp(9) : error C2065: 'R' : undeclared identifier
utilis.cpp(9) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'string'
utilis.cpp(9) : error C2059: syntax error : 'string'
utilis.cpp(10) : error C2015: too many characters in constant
utilis.cpp(10) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
utilis.cpp(11) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
utilis.cpp(12) : error C2015: too many characters in constant
utilis.cpp(12) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
utilis.cpp(12) : warning C4129: '_' : unrecognized character escape sequence
utilis.cpp(12) : error C2001: newline in constant
utilis.cpp(12) : error C2015: too many characters in constant
utilis.cpp(13) : error C2015: too many characters in constant
utilis.cpp(13) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
utilis.cpp(13) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
utilis.cpp(14) : warning C4129: ' ' : unrecognized character escape sequence
utilis.cpp(14) : error C2001: newline in constant
utilis.cpp(14) : error C2015: too many characters in constant
utilis.cpp(15) : error C2018: unknown character '0x60'
utilis.cpp(15) : error C2015: too many characters in constant
utilis.cpp(15) : error C2018: unknown character '0x60'
utilis.cpp(15) : error C2137: empty character constant
utilis.cpp(16) : error C2018: unknown character '0x60'
utilis.cpp(16) : error C2015: too many characters in constant
utilis.cpp(17) : error C2015: too many characters in constant
utilis.cpp(17) : warning C4129: ' ' : unrecognized character escape sequence
utilis.cpp(17) : error C2001: newline in constant
utilis.cpp(17) : error C2015: too many characters in constant
utilis.cpp(18) : error C2018: unknown character '0x60'
utilis.cpp(18) : error C2015: too many characters in constant
utilis.cpp(18) : error C2018: unknown character '0x60'
utilis.cpp(18) : error C2015: too many characters in constant
utilis.cpp(18) : error C2018: unknown character '0x60'
utilis.cpp(18) : error C2015: too many characters in constant
utilis.cpp(18) : error C2001: newline in constant
utilis.cpp(21) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'
utilis.cpp(21) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
utilis.cpp(21) : error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

What am I doing wrong to the point where I cannot create a multi line string?

I've also tried: `cout << BANNER` and get the same output. To me the `to many characters in constant` error isn't making sense, since I've seen banners larger then mine, for example see [here](http://optionparser.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: can you give a link to at least one of this threads or multiple websites. I never heard about this before

Comment: That's a raw string

Comment: Use C++ types, why don't you use an std::string?

Comment: @Papipone I don't think you'd ever want to try and edit the banner at runtime, so if it we're only syntactically correct, I really don't think it'd matter too much.

Comment: @tobi303 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508534/c-multiline-string-raw-literal

Comment: @George Would it be possible to just save the banner into a text file and do something like batch's `type`?

Comment: @jakehimton I don't know what "batch's type" is, but sure, you could read it in from a text file :)

Comment: @George it basically just outputs the contents of a file. Thank you, that gives me an idea.

Comment: @jakehimton this feature works only with c++11, looks like your compiler doesn't support raw string literals. You must use Visual Studio 2013 or higher.

Comment: "You must use Visual Studio 2013 or higher." wut?

Comment: @sumitani As interesting as that is, I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @jakehimton Very interesting, your original code generates different errors here, just removing the [] solved the problem? :)

Comment: @sumitani No, it didn't, but I downloaded `cygwin` with a `gcc` compiler as stated in the comments and that has solved the problem for now

Comment: @jakehimton Yeah, gcc support more C++11 features than Microsoft compiler. (You can check if your ms compiler is up-to-date http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328187/how-to-upgrade-visual-studio-2015-update-1-to-update-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is you put `[]`

```
 const char *BANNER[] = R"BANNER(
```

should be

```
const char *BANNER = R"BANNER(
```

Also, use C++11 or higher.
Works for me with g++ with `-std=c++11`.

Comment: Same issue, during compilation I get the same error.

Comment: @jakehimton did you add -std=c++11 to your compiler flags?

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne I'm using a `cl` compiler, would that make a difference?

Comment: @jakehimton yes, because [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) is not available before the C++11 standard